# Best way to use multiple like statements in XML PATH query

Tags: t-sql, for-xml-path

When I use the "Or" operator (`Secretary_Job_Title like '%Secretary%' or Secretary_Job_Title like '%Assistant%'`) I'm returning too many values.

How can I best use Like statement for Secretary and Assistant in the following query? Thanks in advance!!

```
 SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + secretary
          FROM   [HandshakeProd].[dbo].[sp_attysecrel]
          WHERE  attorney = 'HC\' + Rtrim(p.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
                 AND secretary_job_title LIKE '%Secretary%'
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Assistants]
```

Comment: Hi TT, that worked. My parentheses were not in the correct place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';' + secretary
          FROM   [HandshakeProd].[dbo].[sp_attysecrel]
          WHERE  attorney = 'HC\' + Rtrim(p.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
                 AND (secretary_job_title LIKE '%Secretary%' OR secretary_job_title LIKE '%Assistant%')
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Assistants]
```

Comment: Hi TT, that worked. My parentheses were not in the correct place. Thanks!